# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Protobuf"

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

any of you who knows how to solve this issue having 2 libraries using a different version of another library in iOS flutter pods?

I've seen a lot of posts but not sure if I'm doing something wrong because they did not work for me.

Also, I've tried pod update and does not solve my issue

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Protobuf":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Protobuf

  In Podfile:
    flutter_blue (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_blue/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      flutter_blue/Protos (= 0.0.1) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
        Protobuf (~> 3.11.4)

    mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 2.6.0) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
        MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 1.7.0) was resolved to 1.7.0, which depends on
          MLKitVision (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
            Protobuf (~> 3.12)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue as the logs states is that you are using a specific version of Protobuf while mobile_scanner depends on a different version which can't be resolved.

you can either try to upgrade Protobuf to using version 3.12 or downgrading mobile_scanner to use Protobuf 3.11.4(which I don't recommend since it is a dependency).

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for the reply how can I do to update Protobuf in the other library that is using the older version?(New to all this) :/

Comment: Best approach is to ask the library provider to update it and publish an update. Alternatively, you could fork the podspec and update it yourself